# Azure Mobile Services Client - Using WaitAll on Multiple InsertAsync Tasks

Tags: c#, azure, insert, async-await, wait

I'd like to be able to kick off multiple InsertAsync operations, and then wait until done.
Something of the [proforma] form

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[10];
try
{
    IMobileServiceTable<Record> table = mobileService.GetTable<Record>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Record rcd = new Record();
        tasks[i] = table.InsertAsync(rcd);
    }
}
catch { Assert.fail(); };
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks, 10000);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("WaitAll() has not thrown exceptions.");
}
catch { Assert.fail(); };
```

The WaitAll just times out, and when I look at the tasks in the tasks array, none are running. So clearly I'm using the wrong pattern, but can't see where.
Any insights are hugely appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems either.

Comment: Have you tried to await the call to `Task.WaitAll`?

Comment: I've tried the await on Task.WaitAll but that just hangs, since the tasks aren't actually running ... :).  I'm going to build a real real simple pro-forma in its own project and explore.  Shall report back

Answer (score 0):

OK; solved it. Still no exactly sure why.
The original code that I set out in the question was in an async routine; let's call it insertAsync().
It was called synchronously, since I didnt want the caller to proceed until insertAsync was done.
What I had written before was

```
Task<bool> t = insertAsync();  
t.Wait();
```

But if you do that, everything hangs - ie none of the table inserts ever start.
Comment out the t.Wait() and everything works.